# data is not passing through url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

i am trying to pass an id to a controller through url but the problem is it gives me the id field null
result of the edit link is like
"localhost/home71/project_management/index.php/boq_account/edit?id="

```
$url=base_url();
echo "<td id='edit'><a href='$url project_management/index.php/boq_account/edit?id='$n->id''>Edit</a></td>";
```

i have tried so many ways but not getting any result.one thing to mention that my $n->id is not null it has values but its not showing on the passing id parameter.

Comment: does `$n->id` hold some value?

Comment: than try with my answer, it must work.

Comment: print your id before this echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this-

```
echo "<td id='edit'><a href='$url project_management/index.php/boq_account/edit?id=".$n->id."'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
echo "<td id='edit'><a href='$url project_management/index.php/boq_account/edit?id='".$n->id."'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something as below:

```
echo '<td id="edit"><a href="'.$url.'project_management/index.php/boq_account/edit?id='.$n.'">Edit</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many single quotes near $n->id. Try something like this:

```
echo "<td id='edit'><a href='$url project_management/index.php/boq_account/edit?id=$n->id'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you have data in `$n->id`, use PHP's `urlencode()` as you're passing it to `<a>`.
Here's how:

```
echo "<td id='edit'><a href='$url project_management/index.php/boq_account/edit?id=".urlencode($n->id)."'>Edit</a></td>";
```