# How to send id through url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, activerecord

I want to send my id through url and want to get id in another page.

But how to send id through url Kindly help.

My Views which is not working.

```
<div class='title'><a href="<?php echo $Result->ad_id();?>"><?php echo ucwords($Result->ad_title);?></a></div>
```

Comment: `$Result->ad_id();` is just floating in there, use it with `echo`

Comment: @Ghost i have updated code, i am using echo but it is not working

Comment: What the problem you are facing right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume,

your domain name is  http://www.muhammad.com

You are going pass id to index.php

```
<div class='title'>
    <a href="http://www.muhammad.com/index.php?id=<?php echo $Result->ad_id();?>"><?php echo ucwords($Result->ad_title);?></a>
</div>
```

In index.php

```
$submit_id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

[data is not passing through url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512544/data-is-not-passing-through-url?rq=1)

As an example, to pass `id = 1234` to `test.php`:

`test.php?id=1234`

Then in `test.php`, the value of `id` will be available from `$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='title'>
    <a href="<?php echo $Result->ad_id() . '?variable_name=variable_value' ?> "></a>
</div>
```

This is one way of query string for passing data using `GET` method...

***`protocol://domain_name?variable_name=variable_value`***

for example:
**`http://test.com?sid=128001`**

**So you can fetch the value in other page:**

```
$var = $_GET['variable_name'];
//in this case:
$var = $_GET['sid'];
```

Comment: $result->ad_id(); is my variable in which id exist, and second thing is that how i will write variable value because i am fetching id as a value from db

Comment: have u seen olx in which every ad is showing in list and whenever a user click on any list so it is opened in another page. i want to do this. i hope i have cleared everything, kindly help

Answer (score 0):

This is your given code.

```
<div class='title'>
   <a href="<?php echo $Result->ad_id();?>">
      <?php echo ucwords($Result->ad_title);?>
   </a>
</div>
```

Here, the hyperlink is not correct. If you're  using php without any framework, then add the link first before the id you want to pass.

```
<a href="http://example.com/anypage.php?id=<?php echo $Result->ad_id();?>">
   <?php echo ucwords($Result->ad_title);?>
</a>
```

Now, in the anypage.php, write some code to get the id from the url, i.e.

`$id= $_GET("id");`

Hope, it'll work! :)